# How to make a sort script with PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML Code

```
<form action="sort.php" method="post" >
<select name="option">
<option value="1">Select a category!</option>
<option value="2">Category 1<option>
<option value="3">Category 2</option>
</select>
<select name="option">
 <option value="a">Select a 2nd category!(Optional)</option>
 <option value="b">Category 1</option>
 <option value="c">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['option']))
{
    if ($_POST['option'] == '1') { header('Location: /website'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '2') { header('Location: https://example.com/2'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '2') { header('Location: https://example.com/2'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '2') { header('Location: https://example.com/2'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '3') { header('Location: https://example.com/3'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '4') { header('Location: https://example.com/4'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '5') { header('Location: https://example.com/5'); }
    elseif ($_POST['option'] == '6') { header('Location: https://example.com/6'); }       
}
?>
```

I want to make it so if someone select value "1" & value "a".Then X Link will open. And I want to make the 2nd  button optional. If someone leaves it empty, it will not have any effect. How can I do so?

Comment: you have 2 selects with same name, and why using `elseif ($_POST['option'] == '2')` 3 times ? why `elseif ($_POST['option'] == '4') // or 5 - 6` as they're not somewhere in the select list ? I don't see the logic of what you want/need to achieve here, can you clarify please ?

Comment: if ($_POST['option'] == '1') { header('Location: /website'); }elseif ($_POST['option'] != '' ){ header('Location: https://example.com/'.$_POST['option']); }

Comment: Multiple =='2' was a mistak, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: try my answer @RahulSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need `mutiple elseif`

```
 $arr =array(2,3,4,5,6);

if ($_POST['option'] == '1') 
{ 
  header('Location: /website'); 
}
elseif($_POST['option'] != '' && in_array($_POST['option'],$arr) )
{ 
  header('Location: example.com/'.$_POST['option']);
}
else
{
  echo "may be empty";
}
```

Note: change your `input name` and set `required` to first one

```
<select name="option" required>
<option value="">Select a category!</option>
<option value="1">Category 1<option>
<option value="2">Category 2</option>
<option value="3">Category 3</option>
<option value="4">Category 4</option>
<option value="5">Category 5</option>
<option value="6">Category 6</option>
</select>
<select name="option1">
<option values="">Select a 2nd category!(Optional)</option>
<option value="1">Category 1<option>
<option value="2">Category 2</option>
<option value="3">Category 3</option>
<option value="4">Category 4</option>
<option value="5">Category 5</option>
<option value="6">Category 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made it a lot simple. But, if I select Category 1 in the first  option. And category 3 in the second option, then it opens 1st category page.'s page (i.e Example.com/2)

Comment: did you notice that the first option value i leave empty <option value="">Select a category!</option> @RahulSharma

Comment: I mean, let's say, If someone select Value 2 from option, and value 4 from  option1. Then I wanna open google.com. How to do it?

Comment: if ($_POST['option'] == '2' && $_POST['option1']=='3') 
{ 
  header('Location:http://google.com'); 
}

Comment: I just started to learn to program. Can you please edit your main post, and paste that code their? Thanks, really very much appreciated.

Comment: glad to help you @RahulSharma

Comment: you should add exit; after each header(); if the redirect is the last thing to do here